# Unknown format while uploading image in rails using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using gem carrierwave for uploading image however I got an error in the respond_to statement in controller.

Here is my form.html.erb

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
<%= form_for @admin_cast,html: {multipart: true,:id=>'create-cast'}, remote: true do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group textfield-width">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name,:class=>'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group select-date">
    <%= f.label :birth_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :birth_date,:start_year => 1970,:end_year => 2014, :prompt => { :year => 'Year', :month => 'Month', :day => 'Day'},:html=>{:class => 'form-control'} %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description,:class=>'form-control',:rows=>'5' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :profile_picture %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :profile_picture,:class=>'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group clearfix">
    <%= f.submit :class=>'btn btn-primary pull-right' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

//controller

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @admin_cast.update(admin_cast_params)
    #format.html { redirect_to @admin_cast, notice: 'Cast was successfully updated.' }
    #format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @admin_cast }
    format.js
  else
    #format.html { render :edit }
    #format.json { render json: @admin_cast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js
  end
end
```

end

//model

```
class Admin::Cast < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admin_photos, :class=>'Admin::Photo'
  validates :name,:presence => true
  validates :birth_date, :presence=>true
  mount_uploader :profile_picture, Admin::PhotoUploader
end
```

I really need your help. I've been searching this for one day and I cannot get an answer

Comment: where is your error? share your server log.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for solution still but i got the same issue while submitting form in remote. I got it fixed by installing the gem https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart . Give it a try.